# is it possible to integrate Google Pay in C# window form desktop application

Tags: c#, asp.net, desktop-application, google-pay

I have Develop a Desktop Application in C# window Form. the application about reservation of Pet`s. My Manager assign me a Task to integrate google pay in This desktop application. I need to know is it possible or Not, if Yes then How ? Because in Google pay Guide it is described that this integration is for Mobile and Web.
Please Help.

Thanks

Comment: Use a webview, then use the google pay web guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no, this isn't possible in a desktop application.

Longer answer:

- The Google Pay button will *generally* involve launching a popup window which might not be possible to do with a webview (I haven't tried this myself)
- Google Pay will only be enabled for production integration after it has been reviewed and tested by the Google Pay team and they likely won't be able to do this if it is a Windows desktop application

Answer (score 0):

No. 
What you can do is create an Api that will integrate with Google Pay and consume in your desktop application.

Comment: Please try to be more clear while answering a question.